# What's the least computationally expensive way to verify a message is from who they say they are?

Tags: signature, verifiability, lightweight

We're building an ingame GPS system where only 5 lines of code are executed a second. We're starting to face problems with people spoofing the satellites we use to triangulate. Is it feasible to filter out these messages with such low computing power, and if so, how?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. 5 lines of what code? Any language? Are there libraries? What is a "line" anyway? Is the code visible by others? Is there some sort of storage available? etc...

Comment: This is for a basic programming language called YOLOL. There is no libraries and limited storage. It would be a string of about 8 characters. https://wiki.starbasegame.com/index.php/YOLOL

Comment: Is in-game cryptography really the best solution here? I would think somehow identifying the message's sender in a way that can't be spoofed would work better all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in verifying a signature is to hash the message, which takes a few thousand x86 instructions. Your language doesn't seem to support the logical operations that are common in modern hash functions - implementing those with arithmetic operations will cost you some overhead. So you're talking about hours before you even get to the public key portion of the signature. And you can't use a weak hash function, because your attackers aren't limited to such an under-powered platform to produce their forgeries.

I question if in-game cryptography is the best solution here. Since this is all in a managed environment, it seems like you could simply disallow spoofing of the sender property of these messages.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We're looking into other solutions.